# In XSLT I have a recurring table and want to place column headers on the top of sets of rows, but they come out above every row.

Tags: xslt

My xml input is as follows:

```
<Message>
    <ORC>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <PlacerOrderId>ORD723222-4</PlacerOrderId>
    </ORC>
    <OBR>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <OBRSetid>1</OBRSetid>
    </OBR>
    <OBX>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <OBXSetId>1</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>6</Id>
        <OBXSetId>2</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <OBXSetId>3</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <ORC>
        <Id>9</Id>
        <PlacerOrderId/>
    </ORC>
    <OBR>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <OBRSetid>2</OBRSetid>
    </OBR>
    <OBX>
        <Id>11</Id>
        <OBXSetId>1</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>12</Id>
        <OBXSetId>2</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>13</Id>
        <OBXSetId>3</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <ORC>
        <Id>14</Id>
        <PlacerOrderId/>
    </ORC>
    <OBR>
        <Id>15</Id>
        <OBRSetid>3</OBRSetid>
    </OBR>
    <OBX>
        <Id>16</Id>
        <OBXSetId>1</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>17</Id>
        <OBXSetId>2</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>18</Id>
        <OBXSetId>3</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <ORC>
        <Id>19</Id>
        <PlacerOrderId/>
    </ORC>
    <OBR>
        <Id>20</Id>
        <OBRSetid>4</OBRSetid>
    </OBR>
    <OBX>
        <Id>21</Id>
        <OBXSetId>1</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>22</Id>
        <OBXSetId>2</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
    <OBX>
        <Id>23</Id>
        <OBXSetId>3</OBXSetId>
    </OBX>
</Message>
```

The output should place table headings above the OBX rows like the following output:

```
<ORC>3 ORD723222-4</ORC>
<OBR>4 1</OBR>
<Heading>ID</Heading>
<OBX>5 </OBX>
<OBX>6 </OBX>
<OBX>7 </OBX>
<ORC>9 </ORC>
<OBR>10 2</OBR>
<Heading>ID</Heading>
<OBX>11 </OBX>
<OBX>12 </OBX>
<OBX>13 </OBX>
<ORC>14 </ORC>
<OBR>15 3</OBR>
<Heading>ID</Heading>
<OBX>16 </OBX>
<OBX>17 </OBX>
<OBX>18 </OBX>
<ORC>19 </ORC>
<OBR>20 4</OBR>
<Heading>ID</Heading>
<OBX>21 </OBX>
<OBX>22 </OBX>
<OBX>23 </OBX>
```

The code I have is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Message/*[self::ORC or self::OBR or self::OBX]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ORC">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="Id"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="PlacerOrderId"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OBR">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="Id"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="OBRSetid"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OBX">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="Id"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="OBXSetid"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I put the table header code in the OBX template, but it comes out above each OBX row instead of at the beginning of each set of OBX rows. Where can I place the table header so it comes out in the correct place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the template matching `OBX` to:

```
<xsl:template match="OBX">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::OBX])">
        <Heading>ID</Heading>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="Id"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="OBXSetid"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note:
1. Your stylesheet currently outputs invalid XML due to missing root element;
2. XML is case-sensitive and `OBXSetid` does **not** select `<OBXSetId>`.